# Jade Template - Use URL as link label

Tags: javascript, pug

I have an issue when I add a link inside a paragraph.

The jade template syntax:

```
p Here is link to #[a(href='https://google.com/') google link]
```

The result is: Here is link to [google link](https://google.com/)

**What I want is**: Here is link to https://google.com/

I tried this syntax but it does not work:

```
p Here is link to #[a(href='https://google.com/') https://google.com/]
```

An error happen if the link display has `http://` or `https://`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This appears to work: `#[a(href='https://google.com/') google.com]` although you will be missing the `http://` part in the label.

Comment: Yeap, the issue come because `http://` or `https://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can use a markdown filter to write your link inside the paragraph:

```
p
  | Here is link to  
  a(href='https://google.com/') https://google.com/
```

**EDIT 1**

It also can be done using locals..

```
{
    URL: 'https://google.com/'
}
```

..and interpolation:

```
p Here is link to #[a(href='#{URL}') #{URL}]
```

**EDIT 2**

If single quotes are not hindrance, just do:

```
p Here is link to #[a(href='https://google.com/') 'https://google.com/']
```

**EDIT 3**

It's exactly the same as the **EDIT 1** but without locals:

```
p Here is link to #[a(href='https://google.com/') #{'https://google.com/'}]
```

Comment: I want to make jade template for `a tag` inside paragraph, because a lot of hyper link in a single paragraph, with some other tags, if I split it to the next link, the jade code it too deep for each tag.

Comment: @HuyNguyen To be honest, it seems, I didn't understand what exactly you meant in your comment , but I updated the answer with some extra cases.

Comment: EDIT 3 it what I want. Thanks a lot.